# Нажатие клавиши Enter в таблице QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, keypressevent

После ввода значения в ячейку и нажатия на клавиатуре клавиши **`Enter`**, должна появляться запись в терминале: 'Нажат Enter'.

По факту запись появляется только после второго нажатия кнопки и не каждый раз, а через раз.

Не могу понять как выводить сообщение после первого нажатия?

```
import sys    
from PyQt5.Qt import *    


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.layout_vert_0 = QVBoxLayout()                    
        self.layout_1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout_vert_0)
        self.layout_vert_0.addLayout(self.layout_1)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "PyQt5")    
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()            
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)        
        self.layout_1.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn            
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)        
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        k = e.key()
        print('нажата какая-то кнопка')
        if k == 16777221:
            super().keyPressEvent(e)                                
            print("!!!!! нажат Enter")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)            
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self)                        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("pyqt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На компьютерной клавиатуре клавиша ввода [**Enter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key) и клавиша возврата **`Return`**

- это **две** тесно связанные клавиши с перекрывающимися и разными функциями,
  зависящими от операционной системы и приложения.

Qt различает эти две клавиши.

```
import sys    
from PyQt5.Qt import *    

    
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.layout_vert_0 = QVBoxLayout()                    
        self.layout_1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.tab1.setLayout(self.layout_vert_0)
        self.layout_vert_0.addLayout(self.layout_1)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "PyQt5")         
        
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()            
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)        
        self.layout_1.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
# -------------------------------------------> vv <--------------------------
        row =       self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        column = self.tableWidget.currentColumn()
        print(f'row = {row}; column = {column}\n') # <-----------------------
        
        print(f'Key_Enter = {Qt.Key_Enter}; Key_Return = {Qt.Key_Return}\n') # <--- !!!
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        
    # Реагирование на нажатие 'Enter'        
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # print(f'Нажата кнопка: {event.key()}; {event.text()};')
        key = event.key()

#        if key == 16777221:    не делайте так 

# надо так:
#        if key == Qt.Key_Enter or key == Qt.Key_Return:

# или так:       
#        if key in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):

# или так: если вам важно чтобы tableWidget былв фокусе
# --------------------------------------------> vvv vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-----  
        if key in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return) and self.tableWidget.hasFocus():
            
#            super().keyPressEvent(event)                                
            print(f"!!!!! нажат Enter or Return: {Qt.Key_Enter} --- {Qt.Key_Return}')")

        else:            
            super().keyPressEvent(event)
            
            
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        
        self.widget1 = MyWidget(self) 
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.widget1)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("pyqt5")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]